# I want to save multiple plots to pdf or jpeg

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create plots of a ts object condition on a factor variable in my dataset. I want to save each plot to a jpeg, win. metafile or pdf . Ideally, I would be able to save a decomposition plot, but right now I would settle for a basic time trend for each level o the factor.

Hour is the factor variable in my dataset which I am using the do all my time series analysis by. The data spans 1 1/2 years of daily observations of a variable we can call UQ, which varis by hour of the day. My end goal is time series plots (trends, decomp) of UQ for each hour of the day. 
The code I copied is the following:

```
pdf("HRDecomp.pdf", width = 7, height = 7)
d_ply(DATASET, .(Hour), failwith(NA, function(x){plot(x$DATASET$UQ,main=unique(z))}), .print=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

The error I get is the following:

```
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I am thinking it is related to my inability to load ggplot2 but I don't know. I will post another question on this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When saving mulitple plots to one pdf, you may want to use grid.arrange:

```
pdf("output.pdf")
grid.arrange (plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4 ncol=2,nrow=2)
grid.arrange (plot5, ncol=1,nrow=1)
dev.off()
```